# Cannot load mod_deflate

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate

I'm running CentOS 5.6 with cPanel.

I've rebuilt my apache to have deflate enabled. Here is my EasyApache Build Log:

> ```
>     ./configure
>         --enable-deflate
>         --enable-expires
>         --enable-headers
>         --enable-info
>         --enable-logio
>         --enable-proxy
>         --enable-rewrite
>         --enable-ssl
>         --enable-suexec
>         --enable-unique-id
>         --prefix=/usr/local/apache
>         --with-included-apr
>         --with-pcre=/opt/pcre
>         --with-ssl=/usr
>         --with-suexec-caller=nobody
>         --with-suexec-docroot=/
>         --with-suexec-gidmin=100
>         --with-suexec-logfile=/usr/local/apache/logs/suexec_log
>         --with-suexec-uidmin=100
>         --with-suexec-userdir=public_html
> ```

[...]

> ...checking whether to enable mod_deflate... yes (default)

Within my http.conf there is no LoadModule mod_deflate, and there is no mod_deflate.so within my Modules/ Directory.

What am I doing wrong?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Ok, So I ran this command and it returned this:

> /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -M
>   Loaded Modules:
>       core_module (static)
>    authn_file_module (static)
>    authn_default_module (static)
>    authz_host_module (static)
>    authz_groupfile_module (static)
>    authz_user_module (static)
>    authz_default_module (static)
>    auth_basic_module (static)
>    include_module (static)
>    filter_module (static)
>    **deflate_module** (static)
>    log_config_module (static)
>    logio_module (static)
>    env_module (static)
>    expires_module (static)
>    headers_module (static)
>    unique_id_module (static)
>    setenvif_module (static)
>    version_module (static)
>    proxy_module (static)
>    proxy_connect_module (static)
>    proxy_ftp_module (static)
>    proxy_http_module (static)
>    proxy_scgi_module (static)
>    proxy_ajp_module (static)
>    proxy_balancer_module (static)
>    ssl_module (static)
>    mpm_prefork_module (static)
>    http_module (static)
>    mime_module (static)
>    status_module (static)
>    autoindex_module (static)
>    asis_module (static)
>    info_module (static)
>    suexec_module (static)
>    cgi_module (static)
>    negotiation_module (static)
>    dir_module (static)
>    actions_module (static)
>    userdir_module (static)
>    alias_module (static)
>    rewrite_module (static)
>    so_module (static)
>    bwlimited_module (shared)
>    security2_module (shared)
>   Syntax OK

Which Suggests that deflate is running.

I added this to my httpd.conf with no luck.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript    application/javascript  application/xml
```

What needs to be added to get Deflate to work??

Comment: no expert but didnt you just compile mod_deflate directly into apache so therefor its always on.

Comment: Under Software / Services, did you see an icon called Optimize Website?

Comment: No, I do not see Optimize Website in cPanel/WHM anywhere

Comment: ..and yes, it does turn out that mod_deflate is always on, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you determining that compression is ~not~ working?

Not 100% sure on this one, but I think you need to load the module in your conf, by compiling it in you are just compiling ~support~ for the module...

Try this:

```
# explicitly load the module
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

#
# Deflate output configuration
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript

# take care of silly browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

-sean

Comment: I get this error:httpd: Syntax error on line 32 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: module deflate_module is built-in and can't be loaded

Comment: I didn't need to load the module, but the rest worked a treat. Thanks.

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want to add `--enable-so` to your `configure` options.